# getting values return by commands in stata

Tags: loops, stata, mat

I am trying to run the `reg` and geting back the coefficient values in `Stata`. I did the following. Assume that `y` is dependent variable, `k`,`l`,`m`,`n` are independent variables, and there is a new variable `new` that I created.

```
loc vars k l m n
reg y `vars'

# I know that I can get back the coefficients using mat list e(b) but I  need to 
get coefficient of each variable and use it to compute the elasticity (one at a time).

# so, I run the following loop but it doesn't work.



foreach i in vars {
sca coeff`i' = _b[`i'] # main problem here 
sca cons = _b[_cons]  # main problem here
corr new `i' , c # correlation of new with each independent vars
sca cov_`i' = r(cov_12)
sum `i' 
sca elas_`i' = (coeff`i'*r(mean))/10 # elasticity not working 
}
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to code one of the elasticity commands available through `margins` in Stata 12? Have a look, Stata might be already doing what you want.

Comment: @Fr. : Thanks you. Yes, I can also use `margins` which gives me the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Fr. says, you shouldn't need to do this, given `margins`. But why is your code not working? You are using the wrong syntax for `foreach`.

You should be typing not

```
  foreach i in vars
```

but

```
  foreach i of local vars
```

as otherwise Stata will use the literal text `vars` not the contents of local macro `vars`. The two syntaxes are explained in the help and at greater length in http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0005

Smaller points:

1. The assignment `sca cons = _b[_cons]` should work but you don't need to repeat it every time round the loop.
2. You don't show us your code for generating `new`, so we have to assume that is all right.

By the way, "doesn't work" doesn't mean much. I once compiled a list of about 20 meanings I have encountered, the most important including "is illegal" and "doesn't do what I want". So, giving detail on exactly what happened -- in this case exactly what Stata typed in response -- is always helpful.

Comment: @ Nick: Thank you for pointing out the error and referring to the `Stata` article. Yes, I can also use `margins` which gives me the same answer.